# WPF modify Style at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

Could you please tell me how to change a style Setter at runtime.
I am using Material Design for XAML.
When i press a button i want to change between the Light and Dark Mode.
The Background of the Snackbar changes (done via a script made by the author of Material Design), but the color of the "OK" button doesen't change. Lime on White is very hard to tell apart. So i want to change the Lime OK into the Purple OK.

Here's the initial code

```
     <UserControl.Resources>

            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSnackbarActionButton}" x:Key="SnackbarThemeChangedStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource SecondaryAccentBrush}"/>
            </Style>
        </UserControl.Resources>
         .....
        <materialDesign:Snackbar x:Name="SnackbarMaximumCharacters"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" ActionButtonStyle="{StaticResource SnackbarThemeChangedStyle}" IsActive="True">
                <materialDesign:SnackbarMessage Content="The maximum number of characters is 15" ActionContent="OK" ActionClick="SnackbarMessage_ActionClick"/>
            </materialDesign:Snackbar>
```

(Image1) https://i.stack.imgur.com/oegZM.png

Everything works okay until i change switch to Dark Mode.
When i Switch to darkmode i want to have the following code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSnackbarActionButton}" x:Key="SnackbarThemeChangedStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}"/>
            </Style>
        </UserControl.Resources>
         .....
        <materialDesign:Snackbar x:Name="SnackbarMaximumCharacters"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" ActionButtonStyle="{StaticResource SnackbarThemeChangedStyle}" IsActive="True">
                <materialDesign:SnackbarMessage Content="The maximum number of characters is 15" ActionContent="OK" ActionClick="SnackbarMessage_ActionClick"/>
            </materialDesign:Snackbar>
```

(Image2)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv03P.png(

The same result i can acomplish by writing:

```
   <materialDesign:Snackbar x:Name="SnackbarMaximumCharacters"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" ActionButtonStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSnackbarActionButton}" IsActive="True">
        <materialDesign:SnackbarMessage Content="The maximum number of characters is 15" ActionContent="OK" ActionClick="SnackbarMessage_ActionClick"/>
    </materialDesign:Snackbar>
```

which is the equivalent for the first codebox, and:

```
        <materialDesign:Snackbar x:Name="SnackbarMaximumCharacters"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" ActionButtonStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSnackbarActionMidButton}" IsActive="True">
        <materialDesign:SnackbarMessage Content="The maximum number of characters is 15" ActionContent="OK" ActionClick="SnackbarMessage_ActionClick"/>
    </materialDesign:Snackbar>
```

for the second codebox.

If i modify the code at runtime by hand, everything works, and changes take place, but if i were to do it by code, no change would happen.

---

How can i make this changes by code, when i press a button?

Comment: Have you tried using `DynamicResource` instead of `StaticResource`?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work out

Answer (score 0):

> The difference between StaticResource and `DynamicResource` lies in
>   how the resources are retrieved by the referencing elements.
>   `StaticResource` are retrieved only once by the referencing element
>   and used for entire life of the resource. On the other hand,
>   `DynamicResource` are acquired every time the referenced object is
>   used.

Change your `StaticResource` by `DynamicResource` should do the work.

Comment: Thank you for the short summary about the differences between those 2, but for me it didn't work out, and after 8hours of googling, i decided to ask here, in the hope someone encountered my problem